# Add an opacity transition once a trigger point is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wanting my image to start essentially look as if it is fading out once the image has been scrolled down to the halfway point.

[This is a great example.](https://www.aktivwebsolutions.com/solutions)

I am using waypoints to come up with the trigger point, which is working fine.

I can't figure out how to apply the opacity, especially when it comes to fading out the image the further down you scroll and then to fade back in as the user scrolls up. Do I use an overlay or apply an `opacity: 0` like I have in my snippet?

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```js
$('#servMain').waypoint(function() {
  $('#servMain').addClass('fadeOpacity');
  console.log('scrolled into view');
 }, {
  offset: '-30%'
 });
```

```css
#servMain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Long_March_2D_launching_VRSS-1.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.fadeOpacity {
  opacity 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<section id="servMain">
  
</section>
<section class="sec90">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</section>
```

Comment: first move you script tags in html below `#servMain` and include your css at the top of the page. I am not sure exactly what is happening right now though with current code apart from above.

Comment: Or maybe try `$(this).css('opacity', '0')` instead of adding class `fadeOpacity `. And see if it is working.

Comment: I don't think waypoints is built to handle this scenario. Waypoints is used to trigger something when you scroll to an element (one event), not trigger events _while_ you scroll that element. You might have to write something yourself, or use another plugin like [ScrolMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) which can handle this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with Waypoints, but you can write something yourself.  Here is an example of the javascript needed to set the opacity depending on the scroll (I stole this code from the website you linked):

```
   $(document).scroll(function (t) {
        var $main = $("#servMain");
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var r = (h - window.scrollY) / (h - 400);

        if (r >= 0) { $main.css("opacity", r); }
    });
```

They 400 is like the offset I believe so you can adjust that to your needs.

```js
 $(document).scroll(function (t) {
        var $main = $("#servMain");
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var r = (h - window.scrollY) / (h - 100);

        if (r >= 0) { $main.css("opacity", r); }
    });
```

```css
#servMain {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Long_March_2D_launching_VRSS-1.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="servMain">
  
</section>
<section class="sec90">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

you've got a typo in your css ( forgot semi-column )

```
.fadeOpacity {
  opacity : 0;
```

check this : https://jsfiddle.net/h5mj5ezh/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am looking for a way to do this based on a transitional gain of opacity based on how much the user has scrolled past 50%.